# Will Qt's plugin crash the main program?

Tags: c++, qt

If there is a bad plugin that crashes within itself (inside it's own code part).

Will this cause the program which load this plugin to crash too?

Is it true that the only way to keep the main program safe is to run two process and have IPC?

Comment: Yes a bad plugin can easily crash a main program. The plugin will run in the same address space as the main program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the plugin runs in the same process as the rest of the application, and when something crashes, the whole process crashes. So yes, AFAIK, you do need a separate process to ensure the kind of reliability you're looking for.

That's why WebKit (and its offspring web engines) spawn a separate process for each opened tab.